# Play framework 2 - i18n in javascript files

Tags: javascript, scala, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I am using Scala Play Framework 2. I want multilanguage javascript files and it would be perfect to have the possibility to put `Messages("title.items")` inside javascript files.

To do so, I think we should create a new Asset controller that inject the Lang object.
Is there a better way?
Where could I find some resources about?

Comment: I am embedding an html file with a javascript map with the localized values. It works but it doesn't seem so clean

Comment: You can take a look at this small example I did. Internalization in Scala templates and JS files.

https://github.com/geremora/play2-i18n-sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [JsMessages](https://github.com/julienrf/play-jsmessages) plugin for Play2

Comment: Essentially it is the solution that I was following but packaged in a plugin. Very good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used it this way.

`ApplicationController.scala` .

```
class ApplicationController @Inject() (
  val messagesApi: MessagesApi
) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def messages(): EssentialAction = {
    Ok("window.messagesApi=".concat(Json.toJson(messagesApi.messages("en")).toString).concat(";")).as(JAVASCRIPT)
  }
}
```

`routes`

```
GET /messages.js controllers.ApplicationController.messages()
```